# ScalaTest: setup/tearDown methods for only selected tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I do know that there is the `BeforeAndAfter` trait which allows us to perform setup and tear-down operations before and after every test of a suite.

Is there an alternative that either runs only before and after a suite or runs for selected tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding before and after particular test consider [loan pattern](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#loanFixtureMethods)

```
import org.scalactic.Equality
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class LoanPatternExampleSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  def life(testFun: Int => Any): Unit = {
    println("Doing stuff before the test")
    val meaningOfLife = 42
    testFun(meaningOfLife)
    println("Doing stuff after the test")
  }

  "User" should "do things" in life { i =>
    println(s"My fixture says meaning of life is $i")
    assert(true)
  }
}
```

which outputs

```
sbt:scalatest-seed> testOnly example.LoanPatternExampleSpec
Doing stuff before the test
My fixture says meaning of life is 42
Doing stuff after the test
[info] LoanPatternExampleSpec:
[info] User
[info] - should do things
[info] Run completed in 314 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

[`BeforeAndAfterAll`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.1/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterAll.html) has overrides for methods to be executed once before and after the suite.